# java synchronized block for more than 1 objects?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have two arrays, and I need to synchronize access to them across threads. I am going to put them in a synchronized block. The problem is, I can pass only one of them to 'synchronized' st one go.

How do I ensure that the access to both the arrays is synchronized?
Do I put them in a class and create an object of it?
Or I access the other array only in the synchronized block, and this takes care of synchronized access to it?

Thanks,

Comment: Putting them in a new class may help clarify what you want to do, so I would recommend that. However, that doesn't impact the thread-safety at all. I like the answer that uses explicit locks (below).

Answer (score 21):

Whatever you do **don't** do this:

```
synchronized (array1) {
  synchronized (array2) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

This is likely to lead to [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) unless you are very careful. If you do this approach, you must ensure you have an unchanging partial order on the objects - Google "Dining Philosophers" for discussion of the pitfalls.

Basically what you have to do is create one lock object that you will use if you want to access *either* array and then use that for *all* array access. It's coarse-grained but safe. You could do it this way:

```
public static class TwoArrays {
  private int[] array1 = ...
  private int[] array2 = ...
  private final Object LOCK = new Object();

  public void doUpdate() {
    synchronized (LOCK) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

If you need a finer-grained method you want to use the Java 5+ concurrent utilities such as [`ReadWriteLock`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) but this will be more complicated to implement and error-prone.

Comment: You might as well make `doUpdate` synchronized, then, rather than have the added complexity of the `LOCK` object.

Comment: Actually no, it's best practice not to expose your locks, which is what you're doing when you use this as a lock.

Comment: this makes a question arise - using the nested synchronized block can lead to a deadlock, in case there is another synchronization on the same objects. But would it happen when only the code above is present? No thread could acquire the monitor of array2 if it doesn't already have the monitor of array1. And if it has the monitor of array1, no other thread can have the monitor of array2. Do I have a hole in my reasoning?

Comment: About the first deadlock recipe. Isn't it safe as long as you always have the synchronized blocks in the same order (Admittedly the second example still feels better).

Comment: @Buhb - yes, that's exactly the problem, when locking isn't always done in the same order.

Comment: @abyx - but you are missing his point.  Locking two arrays like that is not a SURE recipe.  Its only is a recipe if different threads COULD lock the arrays in different orders.  If that cannot happen, the code is perfectly safe.

Comment: @Bozho - although it is probably safe to synchronize on this string in this instance, there is no need for it. A new `java.lang.Object` would be smaller and cheaper and do the same job. 99% of the times I see people synchronizing on a `java.lang.String` instance, they're just writing concurrency bugs.

Comment: @McDowell, those instances probably have nothing to do with the fact that synchronisation is done on a String, but on a method variable instead of an object attribute. The attribute name `LOCK` provides enough information as to the intended use.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the responses! this is what I am doing now:

final Object syncObject = new Object();
synchronized (syncObject) {
//accessing my arrays here 
}

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Prior to Java 5, I'd have written things like this:

```
// pre Java 5 code:
Object lock = new Object();
// ...
synchronized(lock) {
    // do something that requires synchronized access
}
```

But since Java 5, I'd use classes from [`java.util.concurrent.locks`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) (personally, I don't find this more complicated or error-prone):

```
// Java 5 Code Using Locks
Lock lock = // ...
lock.lock();
try {
    // do something that requires synchronized access
}
finally {
    lock.unlock();
}
```

If you need read-write locking, here is example implemented using read-write locks from Java 5:

```
private ReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
private Lock rLock = rwl.readLock();
private Lock wLock = rwl.writeLock();

private List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

public String getData(int index) { 
    rLock.lock();
    try {
       return data.get(index);
    } finally {
        rLock.unlock();
    }
}

public void addData(int index, String element) {
    wLock.lock();
    try {
        data.add(index, element);
    } finally {
        wLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Of course, adapt it to suit your needs.